# What are the requirements for an expat to rent a place in Sweden?

Tags: accommodation, sweden, relocation, rental

When moving to Sweden, what are the (common) requirements imposed by landlords on renting an apartment? Are any deposits required? Paperwork?

I'm also wondering if the requirements are different for an expat from the US, for instance, and an immigrant who is a citizen of a country that belongs to the EU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paperwork and deposits for apartments are reasonably similar to what's required in the US though the standards seem to [favor renters](http://bopoolen.nu/laws-regulations/?lang=en). I don't know if it's more or less similar in other European countries (or elsewhere).

Citizenship is [not required](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=sv&tl=en&prev=_dd&u=http://www.bostadsratterna.se/allt-om-bostadsratt/faktablad/diskriminering). Of course, there may be some [racial discrimination](http://www.do.se/Documents/rapporter/Diskriminering%20p%C3%A5%20bostadsmarknaden.pdf) in practice but it's possible to file a complaint. For example, making a non-citizen pay a special deposit was used as a [specific example](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDsQFjAC&url=http://www.fastighetsagarna.se/MediaBinaryLoader.axd?MediaArchive_FileID=e004bece-0507-41cc-9c1a-b4e819a39b10&FileName=Diskrimineringslagen%2b2009.pdf&MediaArchive_ForceDownload=True&Time_Stamp=635076967613482500&ei=m4c9U4nMDbDzyAPZvIGABg&usg=AFQjCNEJKwjy-lZN0XuToAmqUW0jrridDA&sig2=4OlVkix-ZVC3o5teeQhr3Q&bvm=bv.63934634,d.bGQ) of indirect discrimination (I couldn't find an English translation for the linked document).

Besides normal rental apartments, many people live in "housing cooperatives" (bostadrätt). These are somewhat similar to condominiums in practice but different in aspects of ownership. Skipping the details, the reason to mention them here is that it's often possible to rent these "second-hand".